# PHP unlink function use absolute or relative path?

Tags: php, relative-path, delete-file, absolute-path, unlink

this one really puzzles me, if i use the code below in file delete_pic.php, it give me the Warning:  unlink(/upload_pic/image.jpg): No such file or directory in /Sites/delete_pic.php

```
    <?php
$filePath = '/upload_pic/image.jpg';

if (unlink($filePath)) {
echo 'File deleted successfully.';
} else {
echo 'Failed to delete the file.';
}
?>
```

but if I replace with the relative path $filePath = 'upload_pic/image.jpg'; it works, "File deleted successfully."
Both delete_pic.php and upload_pic folder are in root directory. `<img src="/upload_pic/image.jpg">` displays correctly.

Can anyone help me understand? thanks a lot.

Comment: Is the `upload_pic` folder in the real root or the web root? Absolute paths are real paths, not relative to the web root.

Comment: The URL in `<img>` is relative to the web root, not real root.

Comment: @Barmar upload_pic folder is in web root. do you mean in unlink, the path was interpreted as real path not web path? that's really tricky

Comment: Yes, all file functions in PHP treat their argument as a normal pathname. Otherwise, how could they access files outside the webroot?

Comment: @Barmar Gotcha! thanks for your prompt reply!

Comment: In general terms, that isn't how networking works. You don't get full direct access to remote computer hard disk drive. All network paths are an abstraction on their own. Stack Overflow does not have a `questions` directory in the disk root with a `76674257` subdirectory and a `php-unlink-function-use-absolute-or-relative-path` file; it's all virtual.

Answer (score 2):

You can use both absolute or relative paths:

- when you prefix your path with `/` like this `/upload_pic/image.jpg` this is considered an absolute path.
- when you don't prefix your path with '/' like this `upload_pic/image.jpg` this is considered a relative path.